# Show concrete data of array with objects

Tags: php

I want to show a specific data of an array, I have the following code and I am trying to print the `printConcreteStudent` function to print a specific student that I indicate passed through the variable `$name`.

When trying to find the student I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Can not use object of type Student as
>   array

The structure of the array is as follows:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Student)#1 (4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Student1"
    ["lastname":"Student":private]=>
    string(7) "lastName1"
  }
}
```

And the function with which I am trying to print a specific data :

```
function printConcreteStudent($name) {

    foreach($this->students as $key=>$value){

        if($value["name"] == $name){

            echo $value->getName() . " ";
            echo $value->getLastName() . " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you error state you can use object as array. In `$this->students` every object is of type `object(Student)` so you can access the name field by using "key" index. You need to change: `if($value["name"] == $name){` (because cannot use `$value["name"]` as `$value` is object) to:

```
if($value->getName() == $name){
```

Answer (score 0):

students is array of object so value is an object so `$value->name;` is how you will access the name attribute

```
   foreach($this->students as $key=>$value){
     if($name==$value->name){
      //print the attributes...  
     }
   }
```

It's better to lower case both of the values and then compare so that it may find the result even if capital letters are entered as input

Comment: As Student object is may encapsulate (private member) it is better practice to use the getter for that field (as OP use in the if-scope of `getName()` - see my answer

Comment: agreed, this is just for the idea, since the error is due to accessing the object as an array.